# Payment and print receipt part of a bus ticket system

Tags: java, oop

I have to do the last part of my project which is the payment and receipt part. I'm still clueless of how to do the payment part, but I did try to do the print receipt part. I'm using Netbeans 8.2. The coding below is my print receipt code, it builds successfully but doesn't bear any output. Maybe it's because I have to compile all the other codes like the seat numbers, date, time and all before this could print? Not sure if the reason was because i left the main part empty but I don't know what to put in there tbh.

I'm a beginner coder btw and still have a long long long way to go. I will try my best to understand your explanations. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BusPaymentDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


class  Printpaymentdetails { 

       public void Printpaymentdetails () {

        Date timenow = new Date();
        Scanner ticket = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Your Bus E-Ticket: ");

        String date = ticket.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Date: " + timenow.toString());  

        String deptime = ticket.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Time of departure: " + deptime);

        String arrtime = ticket.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Time of arrival: " + arrtime);

        String place = ticket.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Trip to: " + place);

        String buscompany = ticket.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bus Company: " + buscompany);

        int seatnumber = ticket.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Seat number: " + seatnumber);

        double price = ticket.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Price:  " + price);

        System.out.println("This ticket is non-refundable.");
        System.out.println("Please be courteous and do not smoke. Enjoy your trip.");   
       }
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: don't put all the logic into the constructor of the `Printpaymentdetails` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running java code, you're invoking a `main` method, here it is empty, so nothing is run. You would have to add something to the body of this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Printpaymentdetails();
}
```

Comment: I see so that part I guess is resolved. So if I'm wanting to do a payment part, will this do? But it's still not quite right I guess.                                          public interface PaymentMethod {
    enum PaymentMethodType {
         CREDIT_CARD
    }

    PaymentMethodType getType();
}

public class CreditCard implements PaymentMethod {
    String number;
    Date expiration;

    public PaymentMethodType getType() {
        return PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodType.CREDIT_CARD;
    }
}

Comment: Code in comments is often unreadable. If you have another problem - post another question. If the question is not resolved, edit it.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm so sorry. This is my very first time. I'll take note of that. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone had one. You can read some articles on asking questions when unsure here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask